# Spring XD analytic-pmml or analytics-ml-pmml 1.1.1 Release Missing Options

Tags: spring-xd

I am running spring-xd release 1.1.1 and it appears the analytic-pmml and analytics-ml-pmml are missing the options available in the examples in the documentation. I have built the new analytics-ml-pmml from master, but when I look at the processor options I see the following:

xd:>module info --name processor:analytics-ml-pmml
Information about processor module 'analytics-ml-pmml':

outputType   how this module should emit messages it produces

inputType    how this module should interpret messages it consumes

I expect to see the other options in the example such as inputFieldMapping, location, modelName, and outputFieldMapping that are referenced in the documentation here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/analytics-ml-pmml

Am I missing something? Is there an easy fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to build and upload the JPMML module and I could see all the supported module options.

This is what I did:
From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/analytics-ml-pmml,

./gradlew clean test bootRepackage

and then upload to XD module registry using 'module upload' in XD shell:

xd:>module upload --type processor --name jpmml --file /spring-xd-modules/analytics-ml-pmml/build/libs/spring-xd-analytics-ml-pmml-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

Successfully uploaded module 'processor:jpmml'
xd:>module info processor:jpmml - This listed all the supported module options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got any information from the module info command if the pmml module was not uploaded.

Here is what I observe.

> 1.1.1.RELEASE | Admin Server Target: http://localhost:9393 
>   Welcome to the Spring XD shell. For assistance hit TAB or type "help".
>
> xd):module info --name processor:analytics-ml-pmml  Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'analytics-ml-pmml' and type 'processor'

BTW - the reason that the pmml module is not shipped with XD is that the license of the library used to implement the module is GPL.  See https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator/blob/master/LICENSE.txt  This does not allow for us to ship the .jar in the XD distribution .zip file.  That is why the source code lives in the separate repo - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/analytics-ml-pmml

I will made a note of this in the README for the module.